Azure Self Hosted pipeline agent no longer starts when I boot my PC
For the past year or so , I have had an Azure, self-hosted agent on this PC (on which I am typing this message).  It performs my Azure Pipeline build of our application.  But a Windows Update a couple of days ago appears to have made some change that prevents it from starting when I reboot.  At least I think that's it.  It's the only thing that changed on the PC.
I have rebooted a couple of times and every time I do, Azure reports the agent as "offline"
But if I go into the c:\agents folder and manually execute "run.cmd", then yes, the agent starts up and reports as online in Azure.  But that is starting interactively, which I do not want;  I see DOS boxes popping up every time I cancel a job.
When I created it, I set it to run as a service.  That is how I want it to start.
Can anyone tell me how to diagnose this and how to make it start again as a service?  Is there a Windows service that Azure uses for agents I can examine for startup properties or something like that?
I don't want to remove and recreate this agent, I just want to fix the existing one.

Are there any error messages when you reboot the agent/restart the correspondent windows service? Which account/credentials are being used in the Windows service? Check if the password is not expired.

No errors I see.  I went to the Windows Event Viewer and didn't see anything related to that.  But as I noticed when I read the answer from Bright Ran, I no longer have any Windows Service related to Azure Pipelines.  It is as if the Windows Update deleted it.   Because I know I configured it to run as a service and this thing had been running automatically for over a year.

You can try to check with the following things:

On the agent machine, open the Services management window to check and ensure the "Startup type" of the agent service is set to "Automatic" or "Automatic (Delayed Start)".


On Azure DevOps, open the pool where the self-hosted is in, click "Update all agents" to try to update the agent to the latest available version.



After above steps, reboot the agent machine to see whether the agent service can startup automatically.
If the agent service still cannot startup automatically, you might need to remove and reconfigure the agent on the machine.


Wow.  I literally no longer have a service by the name.    There is no service whatsoever in my list that starts with the name "Azure".  I don't know what that Windows Update did, but it appears to have deleted it.  I know I sure didn't.  Is there a way to restore without completely deleting and reinstalling the agent?

I missed the last bit about "remove and reconfigure".  I guess I'll have to do that.   I can't believe that Windows Update deleted one of my services but I think it did.

@Joe, On Windows machine, if you have successfully configured a self-hosted agent to run as a service, you should see an service for the agent is existing on the Services window. Looks like, the Windows Updates cleaned up the agent services from the machine. As far as I know, there is no method to restore the deleted agent services. And yes, you need to reconfigure the agent to let it run as a service.
